# Why is my filter not working? d.DefaultView.RowFilter = cls;

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

I merely want to apply a row filter to my datatable and its not working, no errors, just get back the same datatable.

Ive tried creating a dataview from the datatable in order to apply, but that also doesnt return the filtered list. Im lost as to why this code below doesnt work..

```
DataTable d = processFileData(concatFile);
string cls = String.Format("Column6 NOT IN ({0})", String.Join(",", returnClass()));
d.DefaultView.RowFilter = cls;
```

The cls variable above is a list of int values im trying to use which looks like this:

```
Column6 NOT IN (75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,281,303,405,406,493,599,601,606,610,626,630,639,640,647,648,651,662,664,671,672,680,689,697,701,703,706,709,712,717,718,724,735,740,741,743,744,767,768,769,770,775,780,791,799,800,801,802,803,805,806,807,808,810,811,812,815,816,817,818,820,836,837,873,874,875,879,881,895,896,897,902,903,904)
```

I was hoping to have a new set of records with only the ones that didnt have the condition in my filter.  Original DataTable = 34,945 records, if i manually apply my filter in excel on the file, the expected results should be DataTable = 29,240 records.

Here is example of what im trying to accomplish with the filter:

Original DataTable:

Column1, Column2, Column4, Column5, Column6

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 75

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 75

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 79

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 79

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 79

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 100

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 101

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 700

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 750

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 749

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 755

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 799

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 799

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 804

Expected DataTable After Filtering based on Column6 values:

Column1, Column2, Column4, Column5, Column6

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 100

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 101

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 700

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 750

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 749

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 755

Hello, Today, Food, Fun, 804

Comment: If you want a new DataTable, create it from the filtered view: `var newDt = d.DefaultView.ToTable()`. If the problem is the filter not working, the problem is not here, unless it's just a name mismatch. It can't be a type mismatch, otherwise you'ld get an exception. Or are you?

Comment: @Jimi i def dont get any errors with the above code, i just dont get the results i think i should be getting, i thought that by applying the filter as i did, that anything i do with the datatable after that line, I tried this change just to test that the filter was ok and still nothing                DataTable d = processFileData(concatFile);
            //string cls = String.Format("Column6 NOT IN ({0})", String.Join(",", returnClass()));
            string cls = "Column6 NOT IN (75,76)";
            d.DefaultView.RowFilter = cls;
            DataTable classless = d.DefaultView.ToTable();

Comment: The filter *hides* the filtered rows from the view, the rows are still there, though. If you want to remove them, copy the filtered view to a DataTable. Or filter from the SQL side.

Comment: Well then maybe ive been looking at this all wrong, if the rows are all still there after the filter, what can i do to check that the original datatable has in fact been filtered before i work with the new data records? because we expect the smaller set of records, i need to make sure that im only working with those going forward. so is there a check that i can do to verify that the new set is less than the original set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use linq for this instead of DataView

```
List<int> filter = new List<int>()
            {
               75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,281,303,405,406,493,599,601,606,610,626,630,639,640,647,648,651,662,664,671,672,680,689,697,701,703,706,709,712,717,718,724,735,740,741,743,744,767,768,769,770,775,780,791,799,800,801,802,803,805,806,807,808,810,811,812,815,816,817,818,820,836,837,873,874,875,879,881,895,896,897,902,903,904
            }; 


DataTable output = dt.AsEnumerable().Where((row,index) => !filter.Contains(index)).CopyToDataTable();
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: i made the above changes and looks like this, but im getting a red line under the Contains(index) portion                DataTable d = processFileData(concatFile);
            string cls = String.Format("Column6 NOT IN ({0})", String.Join(",", returnClass()));
            //string cls = "Column6 NOT IN (75,76)";
            d.DefaultView.RowFilter = cls;
            DataTable output = d.AsEnumerable().Where((row, index) => !cls.Contains(index)).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: don't use dataview.rowfilter. instead, use the linq statement in my answer to loop through your datable and save into a new datable all the items that are NOT contained in the list.

Comment: I cleaned it up to this       DataTable d = processFileData(concatFile);
            string cls = String.Format("Column6 NOT IN ({0})", String.Join(",", returnClass()));
            DataTable output = d.AsEnumerable().Where((row, index) => !cls.Contains(index)).CopyToDataTable(); but it doesnt like the index within the Contains ()

Comment: Errors states, cannot convert from int to string

Comment: I think that your cls variable is not a collection, it is type of "string". It has to be a collection of the same type as your datatable column. Then you basically say- save all the values in my datatable column that are not contained in the cls collection to a new datatable.

Comment: Sorry, yes the cls is a string so that i can build the filter format to be applied. the cls is setup like this              private List<int> returnClass()
        {
            List<int> cl = new List<int>();  i found what you meant, i have made a change to read directly from the List<> and testing now.

Comment: We are in an infinite loop, approaching stack overflow. I suggested you not to use dataview object with a string filter but using oneliner linq statement to do the filtering against a List<int>

Comment: Test worked out, but not as i expected still, so the number of rows did drop, but only by 94 less records, i was expecting it to be 5704 less. Do i need to focus on the .Contains?? so clearly the Linq way seems to get me closer, but still not exact.. Where can i focus on trying to get this to return the correct number of records?

Comment: Agreed @SAR, i only have these 2 lines now and its filtering, but only filtering out the 94 records instead of 5704 DataTable d = processFileData(concatFile);
            DataTable output = d.AsEnumerable().Where((row, index) => !returnClass().Contains(index)).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: the List<int> include all the values to be either included or not included. if you say !filter.Contains it takes everything in the original datatable column BUT the filter. if you do filter.Contains it takes only values in datatable that match the filter. it seems that in your filter collection you have only 94 items? it's either take only those 94 or everthing but those 94...

Comment: BTW, if you find my answer useful, i'd love a +1  having it marked as answered. thanks (-;

Comment: So maybe im still a little confused, I have a list of numbers in that LIST<>, in the DataTable i have 34,944 records which have a column that contains numbers.. What im expecting to get back is ALL records that DO NOT have that number in that rows column. It seems that its only removing the first 94 records that dont have that number, but i need it to look thru all 34K records and only return to me the ones that dont have any of those numbers..   @Sar marked as answered and +1( i think i did it right)

Comment: Please see another solution in my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // list of values to be filtered
            List<int> filter = new List<int>()
            {
               75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,281,303,405,406,493,599,601,606,610,626,630,639,640,647,648,651,662,664,671,672,680,689,697,701,703,706,709,712,717,718,724,735,740,741,743,744,767,768,769,770,775,780,791,799,800,801,802,803,805,806,807,808,810,811,812,815,816,817,818,820,836,837,873,874,875,879,881,895,896,897,902,903,904
            }; 

// LINQ statement to do filtering
  IEnumerable<DataRow> unmatchingRows = from DataRow row in dt.Rows
                                      where !filter.Contains((int)row[0])
                                      select row;
  // add to a new datatable
  DataTable output = dt.Clone();
  foreach (DataRow item in unmatchingRows)
  {
      output.ImportRow(item);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but its complaining about the Where line Specified cast is not valid.   Here is how i have it setup                IEnumerable<DataRow> unmatchingRows = from DataRow row in d.Rows
                                                  where !returnClass().Contains((int)row[0])
                                                  select row;


            DataTable output = d.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow row in unmatchingRows)
            {
                output.ImportRow(row);
            }

Comment: What is the data type of your datacolumn? (The column in the datatable) it has to be the same as the list (meaning "int" in your case)

Comment: im adding this comment to clarify what im trying to do and see if anything that has been suggested already will work with little modifications...              DataTable(Source) = 34k records
Expected Filtered = 29k Records
The LIST<int> contains 94 ints i want to remove any record from the 34k records that have that int value, which in turn should result in around 29k records.

if i was doing this in SQl, this is the SQL equivalent:

Select * from (DataTable)
WHERE Column6 NOT IN LIST<int>

New DataTable with ONLY the 29k records in it to continue working with.